# Java debugging only works sometimes

Tags: java, debugging

I've got a little bit strange bug.
I wrote some very little piece of code that just displays a rectangle which I can move by pressing the arrow keys.

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{   
    super.paintComponent(g);

    g.setColor(Color.blue);
    g.fillRect(position_x, position_y, 20, size);
}
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
{
    int code = e.getKeyCode();

    if(code == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
        goUp();
    else if(code == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
        goDown();
    else if(code == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
        goRight();
    else if(code == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
        goLeft();
}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    repaint();
}
public void goDown()
{
    position_y += 20;
    position_x += 0;
}

public void goUp()
{
    position_y += -20;
    position_x += 0;
}
public void goLeft()
{
    position_y += 0;
    position_x += -20;
}
public void goRight()
{
    position_y += 0;
    position_x += 20;
}
```

Whenever I debug, the rectangle should be displayed directly (what it does **sometimes**). But most times, there's just a blank JFrame. I've tried it on another system. And it didnt work there too.

Heres my whole code.

**Main.java**

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class Main 
{
    private static JFrame frame = new JFrame("Snake");
    private static ArrayList<Snake> mySnake = new ArrayList<Snake>();


    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        frame.setSize(500,500);
        frame.setBackground(Color.black);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        mySnake.add(new Snake(50, 50, 60, true));
        frame.add(mySnake.get(0));
    }

}
```

**Snake.java**

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
public class Snake extends JPanel implements KeyListener, ActionListener
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    int position_x;
    int position_y;

    int size;

    Timer t = new Timer(500, this);

    public Snake(int position_x, int position_y, int size, boolean isAlive)
    {       
        t.start();
        this.position_x = position_x;
        this.position_y = position_y;
        this.size = size;

        addKeyListener(this);
        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(true);

    }


    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {   
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.blue);
        g.fillRect(position_x, position_y, 20, size);
    }


    public void checkSelfEating()
    {

    }


    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
    {
        int code = e.getKeyCode();
        if(code == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
            goUp();
        else if(code == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
            goDown();
        else if(code == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
            goRight();
        else if(code == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
            goLeft();
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        repaint();
    }

    public void goDown()
    {
        position_y += 20;
        position_x += 0;
    }
    public void goUp()
    {
        position_y += -20;
        position_x += 0;
    }
    public void goLeft()
    {
        position_y += 0;
        position_x += -20;
    }
    public void goRight()
    {
        position_y += 0;
        position_x += 20;
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
    {
    }
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e)
    {
    }
}
```

Are there any suggestions where the problem could be?

Comment: I would suggest your last call to be `frame.setVisible(true);`. Why you are adding elements afterward?

Comment: @Eypros Simple as that! Worked perfect. Thank you